# Images of Cars with License Plates from Respective Countries

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a database of images of cars with license plates from one country, like France or the USA.

Comment: Did you get a database of USA License Plates?

Comment: unfortunately no sir, I worked with the one in France

Comment: All pictures need to be **labeled**, for instance these pictures are of cars registered in Germany, these pictures are of cars registered in Ghana, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can fell into some copyright issues if you pick any random option or car image. I would suggest you to see [Programmable Car Imagery API.](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/car-imagery-rpc-api) available from [Carimagery](http://carimagery.com/) Probably, it would work for you.

Comment: Do you mean https://www.programmableweb.com/api/car-imagery ?